# $y=e^ {-x}\sqrt{x+2}$. what is the volume of solid formed when shaded region is rotated completely about the x-axis?

Tags: calculus, integration

$e^ {-x}\sqrt{x+2}$. what is the volume of solid formed when shaded region is rotated completely about the x-axis? [image]
I am doing the chapter further calculus in the sub chapter integration by parts. I know how to do regular questions but not this one  I have never encountered a question like this where the solid shaded region is completely rotated about the x-axis- Any help is much appreciated . Thank you.

Comment: I am confused. If you know how to do it, then why don't you just do it?

Comment: @José Carlos Santos i dont know how to do it I understand integration by parts but not this question.

Comment: What happens when you rotate, around x-axis, a tiny area $dA$ at a distance $y$ from x-axis? You need to make an attempt and edit your post.

Comment: @Math Lover i dont understand it at all how do you even know the distance of y?

Comment: $y$ is a variable so there is nothing for you to know. You need to know limits of $y$ for your integration. Do you know how to find volume of a cylinder using integration?

Comment: @Math Love no i dont

Comment: Then my suggestion is to first read that up. Then come back to this question where radius changes as $x$ changes as radius $y$ is a function of $x$.

Comment: When you cut such a solid into thin slices of width $dx$, you get a collection of disks each of volume ..

Comment: @G Cab i know but how do you find the area and how do I use this knowledge in this question?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Just out of curiosity, what if the rotation had been about the $y$ axis?  By the image shown, $f(x) = e^{-x}\sqrt{x + 2}$, is not a surjection.  It seems to me that  identifying, for a given value of $y_1$, all values of $x$ such that $f(x) = y_1$ is no walk in the park.  How would you handle this?

Comment: @user2661923 In principle, [shell integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_integration) would work here, but the computations may be hard to deal with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The volume of rotation about the $x$ axis is given by the following formula: $$\pi\int_{a}^{b}\left(f\left(x\right)\right)^2\,\mathrm{d}x\text{,}$$ where, in this case, $f\left(x\right)=e^{-x}\sqrt{x+2}$, $b=0$ and $a=-2$ (the $x$-intercept of $f\left(x\right)$). $a$ is found by setting $y$ (in the original equation) equal to $0$: $$0=e^{-x}\sqrt{x+2}$$ Either $e^{-x}=0$ or $\sqrt{x+2}=0$. The former will only $\to{0}$ if $x\to\infty$. However, the latter will equal $0$ when $x=-2$ (since $\sqrt{-2+2}=0$). This means the lower bound $a$ is equal to $-2$.

Substituting these values gives the equation: $$\pi\int_{-2}^{0}\left(e^{-x}\sqrt{x+2}\right)^2\,\mathrm{d}x=\pi\int_{-2}^{0}e^{-2x}\left(x+2\right)\,\mathrm{d}x$$ Then, using the integration by parts formula: $$\int{uv^\prime}=uv-\int{vu^\prime}$$ and substituting $u=x+2$ and $v^\prime=e^{-2x}$, the integral $\int_{-2}^{0}e^{-2x}\left(x+2\right)\,\mathrm{d}x$ can be solved: $$u=x+2\implies{u^\prime}=1$$ $$v^\prime=e^{-2x}\implies{v}=-\frac{e^{-2x}}{2}$$ $$\therefore\int{e^{-2x}}\left(x+2\right)\,\mathrm{d}x=-\frac{\left(x+2\right)e^{-2x}}{2}-\int-\frac{e^{-2x}}{2}\,\mathrm{d}x$$ Solving for $\int-\frac{e^{-2x}}{2}\,\mathrm{d}x$ using $u$ substitution: $$u=-2x\implies\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}x}=-2\implies\mathrm{d}x=-\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{2}$$ $$\therefore\int-\frac{e^{-2x}}{2}\,\mathrm{d}x=\int\left(-\frac{1}{2}\times-\frac{1}{2}\right)e^u\,\mathrm{d}u=\frac{1}{4}\int{e^u}\,\mathrm{d}u=\frac{e^u}{4}=\frac{e^{-2x}}{4}$$ Substituting $\frac{e^{-2x}}{4}$ back into the equation gives: $$\int{e^{-2x}}\left(x+2\right)\,\mathrm{d}x=-\frac{\left(x+2\right)e^{-2x}}{2}-\frac{e^{-2x}}{4}=-\frac{2\left(x+2\right)e^{-2x}}{4}-\frac{e^{-2x}}{4}$$ $$=-\frac{\left(2x+4\right)e^{-2x}}{4}-\frac{e^{-2x}}{4}=-\frac{\left(2x+4\right)e^{-2x}-e^{-2x}}{4}=-\frac{\left(2x+5\right)e^{-2x}}{4}$$ Finally, multiply the integral by $\pi$: $$\pi\int_{-2}^{0}e^{-2x}\left(x+2\right)\,\mathrm{d}x=\pi\left(\left.-\frac{\left(2x+5\right)e^{-2x}}{4}\right\vert_{-2}^{0}\right)$$ Evaluating this with the upper and lower bounds and multiplying the result by $\pi$, as shown above, will yield the final answer of $38.95429594394258$, or approximately $39$.

Comment: Hello, welcome to math stuck exchange and thank you very much for helping. but I don't get how you got a=-2

Comment: I got $a=-2$ by setting $y=0$ (the bounds on the $x$ axis are what is trying to be found, and those bounds are found when $y=0$). This means that either $e^{-x}=0$ or $\sqrt{x+2}=0$. The former will only $\to{0}$ when $x\to\infty$, and the latter will equal $0$ when $x=-2$. I will edit my answer to account for this step, if it makes my answer a little more coherent.

Comment: In the graph shown, we see that the shaded region intersects the x axis, i.e. $e^{-a}\sqrt{a+2}=0$. When $a=-2$, $\sqrt{a+2}=\sqrt{-2+2}=\sqrt{0}=0$. Hence $e^{-a}\sqrt{a+2}=e^{2}\sqrt{-2+2}=0$ when $a=-2$.

Comment: thank you please could you please add it to the answer.

Comment: when i tried to integrate it i got $((x+2)1/-2x e^ {-2x}-1/4 x e^{-2x}$ how did you get $\pi\left(\left.-\frac{\left(2x+5\right)e^{-2x}}{4}\right\vert_{-2}^{0}\right)$ where did the 5 come from?

Comment: I have made another edit to my answer, explaining the integration by parts

Comment: Thank you very much I can not thank you enough.